# td not taking display : block in ipod device chrome browser

Tags: block, html-table, ipod

Hello i'm having an issue in table responsive.all devices are working fine with display:block for td but in ipod device chrome browser is not taking display : block.
i want it to take full width.

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
    <th>value</th>
    <th>value</th>
    <th>value</th>
    <th>value</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>value</td>
    <td>value</td>
    <td>value</td>
    <td>value</td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

Style :

```
table, tbody, tr{display:block; width:100%;}
td{width:96%; padding:0 2%; display:block;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Now i found the issue.i have commented this meta tag and now the display block is working fine.can anybody tell me what was the issue with this meta tag and for what this meta tag is being used??

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=8"
```